What does going "alive into Sheol" mean in Numbers 16?
Parshat Korach contains a curious phrase in Moses's admonition to Korach and the resulting consequences:

וְאִם־בְּרִיאָה יִבְרָא יְהֹוָה וּפָצְתָה הָאֲדָמָה אֶת־פִּיהָ וּבָלְעָה אֹתָם וְאֶת־כׇּל־אֲשֶׁר לָהֶם וְיָרְדוּ חַיִּים שְׁאֹלָה וִידַעְתֶּם כִּי נִאֲצוּ הָאֲנָשִׁים הָאֵלֶּה אֶת־יְהֹוָה׃
But if the Lord creates a new thing, and the earth opens her mouth, and swallows them up, with all that appertain to them, and they go down alive into She᾽ol; then you shall understand that these men have provoked the Lord. (Num 16:30 Koren Bible)

...

וַיֵּרְדוּ הֵם וְכׇל־אֲשֶׁר לָהֶם חַיִּים שְׁאֹלָה וַתְּכַס עֲלֵיהֶם הָאָרֶץ וַיֹּאבְדוּ מִתּוֹךְ הַקָּהָל
They, and all that appertained to them, went down alive into She᾽ol, and the earth closed upon them: and they perished from among the congregation. (Num 16:33 Koren Bible)

What does the phrase "descend alive into Sheol" mean in this context? Tanakh depicts Sheol as the destination of the dead, so how exactly does one descend alive into Sheol?

At what point did they die? If ever

Toldot Yitzchak explains exactly what Sheol is: חיים שאולה האחרון משבעה מדורי גיהנם שנאמר ישובו רשעים לשאולה ואז"ל לדיוטא התחתונה ואמר ישובו ולא אמר ירדו שאחר שנשרפין באש גיהנם חוזרים ומתחדשים כבתחלה לשיהיו נשרפין עוד וכן חלילה לדורי דורות וארז"ל שאול חציו אש וחציו ברד והרשעים קופצים שם מאש לברד ומברד לאש כההוא טייעא ששמע שהיו אומרים משה אמת ותורתו אמת ואנחנו בדאים:

See Chatam Sofer on 16:30

וירדו חיים שאולה י"ל לשון חיים כי נתחייבו כמו ר"ן איש כי לולי שנתחייבו
שריפה לא ה' משה יועץ אותם לכנוס לסכנת קטורת אלא שנתחייבו כבר בשריפה
מתחלת מחלוקת וא"כ גם דתן ואבירם נתחייבו שריפה אלא שלא רצו לעלות להקטיר
ע"כ ירדו לאש של גיהנם וישרפו שם ויקבלו עונשם אלא לכאורה טרם רדתם אל
האש של גיהנם כבר יצאו נשמותן מהבל וחבטה דנפילה נמצא לא נשרפו ע"כ התפלל
שירדו חיים שאולה ולא ימותו עד יגיעו לתוך שלהבת של הגיהנם:
"And they descended alive into Sheol." In explanation of the wording "alive," it's possible to say that they were condemned like the 250 men. For if they had not been condemned to burning, Moses would
not have advised them to enter into the danger of the incense. Rather,
they were already condemned to burning from the beginning of the
dispute. Therefore, even Dathan and Abiram were condemned to burning,
but they did not want to go up to offer incense. Therefore, they
descended to the fire of Gehenna and were burned there, and they received
their punishment. But apparently, before they descended into the fire
of Gehenna, their souls would have already left them due to the polluted air and the
impact, so they would not be burned. Therefore, he prayed that they
would descend alive to Sheol and not die until they reached the midst
of the flames of Gehenom.

Also see ביאור יש"ר

וירדו חיים שאלה, שלא ימותו בנפלם, אלא ישארו חיים מתחת לארץ איזה זמן
כדי שיכירו רשעתם ואולי ינחמו מרעתם קודם מיתתם, וזה כדברי האומר שיש להם
חלק לע"הב ועליהם הכתוב אומר ה' ממית ומחיה מוריד שאול ויעל:
"And they will go down alive into Sheol," meaning that they will not die by
falling, but rather they will remain alive beneath the earth for a
certain time, so that they may recognize their wickedness and perhaps
repent of their evil before their death. And this accords with the opinion that they have a portion in the World to Come, and concerning
them it is said, 'The Lord kills and brings to life; He brings down to
Sheol and raises up.'"

